# Django WSGI Multithreading and Connection Problems

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I've followed Graham's instructions to integrate Apache with Django using mod_wsgi: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html, but still experience problems with connections and response time. Since it happens randomly and there is no any errors in Apache log files, it's difficult to understand what's going on.

My Apache is built with pre-fork and is configured as follows:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</IfModule>
```

The WSGI related config:

```
LogLevel info
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgix
WSGIDaemonProcess somename user=apache group=apache threads=25 processes=1
WSGIScriptAlias / /wsgi-dir/script.wsgi
WSGIImportScript /wsgi-dir/script.wsgi process-group=somename application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory /wsgi-dir/script.wsgi>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   WSGIProcessGroup  somename
</Directory>
```

In a request processor I use the following to monitor the active threads:

```
logger.info("Active threads: {0}".format(threading.active_count()))
```

I've noticed that in spite of 25 threads maximum that I have in the config, the active thread count is never bigger than 4, at the same time some clients can wait for a new connection for more than 1 minute, while a request processing time is around 2 seconds.

If a request reaches the server, it's processed fast, but there are cases (approximately 1 per 100 requests) when a client just waits for a connection and can even time out occasionally because of the Apache's limit:

```
Timeout 60
```

I think, this kind of behavior could be easily unnoticed in web app world, where 1 request in 100 doesn't play a significant role (user can just re-load a page), but in the world of services it's really a problem.

I can't understand this - if all threads are busy serving other clients, why doesn't Django spawn yet another thread? If it's not about threads, then what it could possibly be? App reload problem that Graham was writing about?

Here are my versions:

```
python26-2.6.8-3.30.amzn1.x86_64
Django-1.4.3
mod_wsgi-3.2-1.6.amzn1.x86_64
Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

================== First Update with Graham's Suggestions Implemented ================================

Graham et al,

Thank you for the comments and suggestions. I've checked mod_wsgi version and it's 3.2 (see above).
My WSGI config looks like follows now:

```
LogLevel info
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgix
WSGIDaemonProcess somename user=apache group=apache threads=25
WSGIScriptAlias /  /wsgi-dir/script.wsgi process-group=somename application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory /wsgi-dir>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

It was enough to launch 50 EC2 clients with each of them sending a couple of messages to the service @ boot time, to see a delay of 49 seconds for one client, while an average response for all other clients is 2.2 secs with a maximum of 7 secs.

I've checked the app log file and found that a delta between "request received" and "response sent out" was 0.16 second for the delayed request while it's 49 secs delay from a client's point of view.

It leaves us with two possibilities:

1. A client was not able to establish a connection for almost 49 seconds
2. A connection was established, but the server (actually Django/WSGI internals) was not able to read the request fast.

It's difficult to say if it's #1 or #2, because I use a Python's "requests" module on the client to connect to the service. I think that it's #2 though, because if delays goes a little bit higher than 64-65 seconds, an Apache send/receive timeout kicks in and I could see that in Apache's log files.

Here is what I'll try to do to clarify it further:

1. Create a simple controller like below:

   def listener(request):

   ```
   logger.info("Started, active threads: {0}".format(threading.active_count()))    
   time.sleep(3)
   logger.info("Finished, active threads: {0}".format(threading.active_count()))    
   return HttpResponse('OK')
   ```

Note: logger will log the time as well.

1. Create a simple stat interface (I don't want to analyze logs on all client's EC2's):

   def log(request):

   ```
   id = request.REQUEST['id']
   time = request.REQUEST['time']
   res = request.REQUEST['res']

   if (id and time):
       logger.info("STAT Instance: {0}, Processing time: {1}, Response: {2}".format(id,time,res))

   return HttpResponse('OK')
   ```

Clients will work like this:

1. Send a couple of requests to 'listener' URL and calculate processing time on client
2. Send processing time along with EC2 instance id to the 'log' URL

   If I'm able to reproduce the issue with this simple approach, it'll become reproducible and I hope Django team will be able to take it from there.

Any other suggestions are appreciated as well. Many thanks to everyone who has answered.

================== Second Update on Suggested Testing ================================

I've implemented the suggested listeners and could reproduce the issue and hope that everyone else would be able to do the same - you'll just need an AWS account to be able to launch a big number of EC2 clients - 50 will usually suffice, but sometimes I needed to go to 100 to see the delays.

The interesting thing was that the # of active threads gradually grew to 8 from 1 in this test, probably because on average a processing time on the server has increased, so it does work, but still is not sufficient to prevent delays.

I put my client's script to an EC2's user data and it looked like below. If you need a quick instruction about  how to create an auto-sclaing group with all those clients, please let me know.

```
#!/bin/bash

do_send() {

        d1=`date +%s`
        res=`python ~ec2-user/client/fetch.py ${URL_ROOT}/init/`
        res=`echo $res | tr '\n' ' ' | tr ' ' +`
        d2=`date +%s`
        delta=`expr $d2 - $d1`
        echo $ami $ins $res $delta >>$LOG
        curl -s  "${URL_ROOT}/stat/?id=$ami&time=$delta&res=$ins:$res" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

URL_ROOT=<SERVICE-ROOT_URL>
LOG=~ec2-user/log.txt

ins=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 2>/dev/null`
ami=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id 2>/dev/null`
echo "Instance=[$ins]" >$LOG

# First request
do_send

# Second request
do_send
```

fetch.py client looks like this:

```
@author: ogryb
'''
import requests
import datetime
import socket

from optparse import OptionParser
usage = "usage: %prog [options] init_url\n   init_url - http://<host>/init/ server's address"
parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
parser.add_option("-i", "--id", dest="id",
                  help="instance ID", metavar="STRING")
parser.add_option("-p", "--phost", dest="phost",
                  help="public hostname", metavar="STRING")
parser.add_option("-l", "--lhost", dest="lhost",
                  help="local hostname", metavar="STRING")
parser.add_option("-t", "--type", dest="type",
                  help="instance type", metavar="STRING")
parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
                  action="store_true", dest="quiet", default=False,
                  help="Quiet mode")
(opt, args) = parser.parse_args()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
if (not opt.quiet):
    print ("=== Getting metadata:\t{0} {1}".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), ip))
if not opt.id:
    r = requests.get(url='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id')
    opt.id = r.text
if not opt.phost:
    r = requests.get(url='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname')
    opt.phost = r.text
if not opt.lhost:
    r = requests.get(url='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname')
    opt.lhost = r.text
if not opt.type:
    r = requests.get(url='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type')
    opt.type = r.text
body = "id={0}&phost={1}&lhost={2}&type={3}".format(opt.id, opt.phost, opt.lhost, opt.type)
if (not opt.quiet):
    print ("=== Start sending:\t{0} {1} {2}".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), ip, opt.id))
r = requests.post(url=args[0], data=body, verify=False)
if (not opt.quiet):
    print ("=== End sending:\t{0} {1} {2}".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), ip, opt.id))
print r.text
if (not opt.quiet):
    print "Request Body={0} url={1}".format(body,args[0])
    print "Response: {0}\n{1}".format(r.status_code, r.text)
```

============ 03/19/13 - 23:45 Additional Info from Error Log ===

I've changed Apache log level to debug and found the following in Apache error_log. Please let me know if it can be the reason of delays and what can be done about this. I've read somewhere that 'KeyError' is harmless, but you never know.

A client got delayed for 41 seconds @ 6:37:28. The closest event for the error log has happened @ 06:37:15:

```
Wed Mar 20 06:37:15 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27005): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 20 06:37:15 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27005): Attach interpreter '
```

The full error log is below:

```
Wed Mar 20 06:29:45 2013] [info] Server built: Oct 21 2012 20:35:32
[Wed Mar 20 06:29:45 2013] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Wed Mar 20 06:29:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26891): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:29:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26892): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:29:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26893): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:29:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26895): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:29:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26894): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:37:15 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 27005 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Mar 20 06:37:15 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Mar 20 06:37:15 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 27005 for (*)
[Wed Mar 20 06:37:15 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27005): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 20 06:37:15 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27005): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:10 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 27006 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:10 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:10 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 27006 for (*)
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:10 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27006): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:10 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27006): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:11 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26874): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:11 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26874): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:11 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26874): Terminating Python.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:11 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140627014572000,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:11 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26874): Python has shutdown.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:44 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 27007 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:44 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:44 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 27007 for (*)
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:44 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27007): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:44 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=27007): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26880): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26880): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26880): Terminating Python.
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:45 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140627014572000,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Mar 20 06:38:45 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=26880): Python has shutdown.
```

Comment: Oleg, can you tell us a bit more about the models and what the clients are requesting when the problem occurs? Perhaps a specific view/model that causes the issue, etc. I'm thinking of database/memory issues.

Comment: There is no really models or views in my app, it's a service that has a couple of endpoints mapped through urls.py. It runs in AWS and it's in experimental stage. I'm trying to test the performance by launching hundreds of EC2 clients in AWS. The app doesn't use a DB or any other persistent storage at all. It calls some AWS API's, generates a response and sends it back to a client. As I've mentioned, processing itself after a request is received by the service is around 2 seconds (this is what I see in server logs), but on client approximately 1% of requests are delayed or timed out.

Comment: remember, you are using threads - so you will be hit by GIL, check the same thing with multiple processes instead threads

Answer (score 0):

The configuration:

```
<Directory /wsgi-dir/script.wsgi>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   WSGIProcessGroup  somename
</Directory>
```

should be:

```
<Directory /wsgi-dir>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   WSGIProcessGroup  somename
   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Directory>
```

for a start.

The WSGI application with what you had would be running in embedded mode and not daemon mode when handling requests. That was because path to Directory directive was wrong, not being the directory as it should. You can't use the file path as you did. You should validate where it is running using:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode

At the same time, you would have loaded a redundant copy in daemon mode processes that never got used by virtue of WSGIImportScript.

Even after fixing the directive path, the preloading was in different sub interpreter to where requests were handled. You need the WSGIApplicationGroup as given above to ensure that they are in the same sub interpreter (application group).

If using mod_wsgi 3.0+, you would be better off deleting WSGIImportScript directive, and instead using:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /wsgi-dir/script.wsgi process-group=somename application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory /wsgi-dir>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Specifying process-group and application-group at same time with WSGIScriptAlias, does away with need for separate WSGIProcessGroup and WSGIApplicationGroup. Specifying both also has side effect of preloading script, thus replacing what WSGIImportScript was doing, and thus why WSGIImportScript can be removed.

As to performance issues of why requests taking so long, you might install and try New Relic to dig into where the problem is.

For general Apache configuration, also suggest you read my slides from PyCon US talk I just did:

- http://www.slideshare.net/GrahamDumpleton/pycon-us-2013-making-apache-suck-less-for-hosting-python-web-applications

The video should be up by end of the week.

My PyCon talk from last year should also be of interest.

- http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

Comment: Graham, thank you so much for the quick answer. I enjoy reading your posts. Unfortunately the suggested change didn't help. I'll update the main qs shortly to provide details and make some suggestions.

Comment: The only thing I can clarify on at this point perhaps is that seeing a low active thread count when using mod_wsgi daemon mode is normal. Although 25 threads are created, that is at the Apache level. Those threads exist in a lifo, meaning that it will always try and use the most recently used threads for a subsequent request. What this means is that if the Apache level thread in the lifo stack never gets used, because there is insufficient requests getting through to see it get that far down the stack, then the threads never get activated as Python threads.

Comment: So, if you aren't seeing many threads, it may indicate that requests aren't even getting to the WSGI application process or even Apache as a whole.

Comment: As you can see from my last update, the # of threads does grow when a processing time grows on the service, but it doesn't help. Requests do reach the controller but with delays. If delays are to big, Apache times out connections.

Comment: I've just changed Apache's LogLevel to 'debug' and included the error_log to the main thread. Please take a look, probably it'll give you some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing out of the ordinary in the logs except that it shows you are using an old mod_wsgi version. BTW, have you tried sending requests with something other than your fetch.py script to verify it isn't some how the issue. Have you also tried using a different IP address to the link local address that AWS is assigning? You could also try 'traceroute -p 80 169.254.169.254' and see how long it takes. You could even telnet to port 80 and verify how long it takes to connect. IOW, try ways of verify connect time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer and for not providing too many details, but this is NOT a Django or Apache problem. It's a problem of the environment where it runs. I know exactly what is wrong with the "environment", but can't disclose more details because of an NDA. I hope you understand what I mean by the "environment".

Yet another hint: when I've made an assumption in the original post that it's #2 I was wrong - it's actually #1.

I think that knowing that it's not a Django or Apache problem is a huge help for everyone who's still researching this. I don't care how many downvotes or upvotes I'll get for this answer, just wanted to help, because I know how much time it takes to research all that.

Thanks.